# Is the red eye Skitter a new character from season 2?

Tags: falling-skies

In the season 2 of Falling Skies, there is this Skitter with a red eye that we see regularly.

Somehow, I'm under the impression I saw him in season 1. Or, did he get his eye injury during season 1?

Maybe I imagined all this, one year passed since I saw season 1...

Comment: I just watched season 1 in its entirety, and as far as I know, no Skitters that were seen close-up remained alive by the end of the season. I also don't remember any Skitter explicitly having a red eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Red Eye was first clearly seen in the season two opener "Worlds Apart" of Falling Skies.** He may have had a cameo or shadowy appearance in the season one finale.

Spoilers follow:

> He attacks Tom Mason rendering him unconscious during an interrogation on board the alien spacecraft. Red Eye then stalks and follows Tom back to the Second Mass using a bio-mechanical implant that is later removed from Tom's eye. The device returns to Red Eye.

Red Eye follows Ben and communicates telepathically with him.

> He will eventually be captured and offers the leadership of the Second Mass information regarding the alien Overlords. Red Eye reveals  to Tom, an uprising among the skitters against the Overlords and offers Tom an alliance between their two forces.